# how to get the key value from the json data in the loop and push it another varibale in JavaScript + angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> Hi i do have a less knowledge in javascript i need to get the key
>   value from the json data and i need to be store in varibale because i
>   need to be push the values in the grid.

```
var invertor =[{
    "InvId": "1",
    "InvDt": "20170220",
    "LastReading": "0",
    "ReadReading": "0"
  },
  {
    "InvId": "1",
    "InvDt": "20170221",
    "LastReading": "0",
    "ReadReading": "12"
  },
  {
    "InvId": "4",
    "InvDt": "20170221",
    "LastReading": "12",
    "ReadReading": "25"
  }];

this is my json data from here i need to get LastReading and ReadReading value in the second loop beacuse i need to push my data to grid

var tabledata=[];
 var inventordata=[];
 for(var i=0;i<invertor.length;i++){
    debugger
  var tdata={
   "heading":"InvId: "+i,
   "Date":"Date :"+i
  }
  tabledata.push(tdata);
 }
 $scope.tablearray=tabledata;




in this loop i need to get LastReading and ReadReading values to push in the grid


  for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
  var tdata={
   "Last":"invertor.Last: "+i,
   "Read":"invertor.Read: "+i
  }
  inventordata.push(tdata);
 }
 $scope.inventorarray=inventordata;
```

my html Code is here

```
   <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td ng-repeat="data in inventorarray"> <p ng-if="$index%2==0"> Last Reading</p><p ng-if="$index%2>0"> Read By</p> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr  ng-repeat="data in tablearray"> 
      <td> {{data.Date}}</td>
       <td ng-repeat="data in inventorarray"> <p ng-if="$index%2==0"> {{data.Last}}</p><p ng-if="$index%2>0">{{data.Read}}</p> </td>
                     </tr>
```

> those values which im getting i need to be push here.[image]

Comment: Is this angularjs? Please tag your question with it.

Comment: this angularjs but im doing javascript

Comment: Please provide in your question what result you expect to have in the variable `tableData` and `inventoryData` for the sample data you have given.

Comment: Inverter: 0  Inverter: 1  Inverter: 2 
Date Last Reading Read By Last Reading Read By Last Reading Read By
20170221 0 12 0 12 12 25   i want  to display my data in this way

Comment: @trincot please check my IMG

Comment: You really need to provide more information. What is the role of `InvId`? Does it have anything to do with the number in the header of your table: "Inverter: 0"? You have "ReadReading: 0" in your first data element? Where is it represented in the table output? Is there any aggregation of data that pertains to the same date? ...etc.